# Flexbox - cannot center vertically and horizontally [fullPage.js]

Tags: flexbox, centering, fullpage.js

I am trying to center the content of a flexbox vertically and horizontally but it doesn't seem to work:

Here is the CSS:

```
#about{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
.btn-about {
    -webkit-border-radius: 2;
    -moz-border-radius: 2;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #2A77C8;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 1em 3em;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="section" id="about">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="btn-about">Wer bin ich?</div>
</div>
```

Thank you very much for your support!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry! The mistake was mine. I am using fullPage.js and the flexbox centering does not work unless you initialize the function with the option:

```
verticalCentered: false
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
html,body, .section{
   width:100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

in addition to above css

Check https://jsfiddle.net/1Lgovkdr/1/

Comment: @AliMehdi - How do you know the OP wants width/height 100% on the body? It's not needed required, as long as `.section`'s parent element has a height defined.

Comment: it may be browser compatibility issue on your side. Make sure you are on latest browsers.. Check the browser list which flex supports on http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp

Comment: Could it be because I am using fullPage.js?

Comment: You have to check your css.. May be your current css is being overriden